# some steps doesnt work from eevee to cycles blender 2.9

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

hello i just try follow some tutorial in youtube and i forget to change the render engine from eevee to cycles, but when i change the card little bit different the masking is not transparent anymore can somebody explained?? i am very new in blender :)

this the tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-rxbmpcBDIc&ab_channel=FelineEntity

[image: the result use eevee]

[image: when i try in cycles]

Comment: hello, maybe pack your images (File > External Data > Pack All Into .blend) and share your file (copy paste the link it will give you): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: what do you mean images?? did you mean the black and white?  i use that a image texture, and I'm confused whether .blend and .blend1 are the same? i ams o newbie in blender :) sorry if my grammer so broken :)

Comment: you just need to do File > External Data > Pack All Into .blend, so that the images you're using are now part of the file. Share .blend, not .blend1

Comment: blend1 is equivalent to “blend before the last session.” Every time a blend is opened, a blend1 is saved immediately.  PS: an “image texture” is equivalent to “an image file being used as a visual texture”, and of course uses an image file. “Pack” means “store files within the blend file” rather than the default, which is simply storing a path to the needed file. If I have a model of a painting that uses an image in my Pictures folder, by default the image will not be in the blend file, and thus someone else opening the blend file will see blank pink, AKA “you don’t have the image.”

Comment: @moonboots like this :https://pasteall.org/blend/4d7a2d862cbb4101a20b174ddf2021d2 sir?? :)

Comment: what do you want exactly to be transparent? Your window can't be transparent as it has an image on its face

Comment: @moonboots I've been hiding the mask collection but it still same, but in the tutorial the face side is transparent [![][1]][1]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEkHr.jpg

Comment: In the material settings > Viewport Display, you have the Backface Culling option activated, it makes the face transparent from one side in render preview, but if you render you'll see the image in both Eevee or Cycles, so I'm not sure what you mean, do you want this part to be opaque or transparent? If you want it to be transparent, select the material and make it transparent in the Shader Editor (for Eevee don't forget to choose Blend Mode > Alpha Blend)